# Having trouble creating a tooltip for a button?

Tags: jquery, html, tooltip

I'm a beginner and would like to get some help and see where I'm making a mistake. I would like it so the buttons named "Dealer" and "Private Party" show a tooltip box when scrolling over them.

I can provide more detail if needed

Thanks in advance

HTML:

```
<div style="height:200px; text-align:center; float:left; display:table;">
                                <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">
                                <form id="dealer" action="">
                                    <input type="submit" class="price-button" value="Dealer">
                                </form>
                                <form id="private" action="">
                                    <input type="submit" class="price-button" value="Private Party">
                                </form>
                                </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: [jQueryUI Tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `title` attribute on your tag. Something like this:

```
<input type="submit" class="price-button" value="Dealer" title="your tooltip goes here...">
```

[Example at JSFIDDLE follows](http://jsfiddle.net/M4ge8/).

Comment: Is there anyway to make it appear quicker and adjust the location where it shows up?

Comment: Yes, but you will need some JavaScript to do that.

Comment: How do I go about doing that? BTW, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: For me to adjust location do I need to play around with "position"